# Start Stop Button in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this simple VBA code to include the start and stop button.  after I click the On button to start the Do loop the excel stays busy and i can not click Off button to stop the loop.  Can you please help?

```
Public ONOFF As Boolean

Sub ON_Button()
    ONOFF = True
    Do While ONOFF
        Matha
    Loop
    MsgBox ("Exit Matha sub")
End Sub

Sub OFF_Button()
     ONOFF = False
End Sub

Sub Matha()
Dim X, Y, Z
    X = 1
    Y = 2
    Z = 5
    Z = X * Y + Z
End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580330/excel-vba-interrupt-code-execution-not-by-hitting-escape) SO post on how to use DoEvents as recommended by @iDevloop.

Answer (score 2):

Did you assign the Off_Button to the "On" button ? Add a debug.print with a text to make sure it works
If that's not the problem, try adding a DoEvents in you loop to allow Excel handling your click.

Building such a loop will eat all your processor time (at least the core devoted to Excel). For a better solution, check this: [How To Create a Timer Event Using the Windows API Functions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180736/en-us).